# RSI Divergence Strategy Entry

Tags: pine-script

I am using the divergence indicator from tradingview and I am trying to implement the hidden bull condition as an entrypoint for a strategy. The thing is that the indicator drawn by plotting uses an offset of -5 subtracted from the hiddenbullCond and it's not allowing me to use the same offset on the entry. Any ideas? I thought about using the position of the plot as an indicator for start entry but dont know how I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The offset is due to the fact that pivots aren't confirmed at the time of the peak/valley only afterwards. Once the pivot is detected the shape is plotted on an historical bar, not the current bar. You are only able to detect the divergence the same way : with the delay. If you use it as a signal to enter you will only be able to enter after the fact as well. The best you can get is to just use `bullCond` or `hiddenBullCond` etc as the entry conditions.